# RESTfully fetch a JSON list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am writing a simple RESTful controller. So far, I am able to retrieve a single JSON object of type `Employee` by calling `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/5`. But I am NOT able to retrieve a collection of `Employee` objects when calling `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/`. This gets me the following error.

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'employee'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Same thing happens when I am trying to save a new employee.

**EmployeeApiController.cs**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/employee")]
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{

    readonly EmployeePersistence persistence;

    public EmployeeApiController()
    {
        persistence = new EmployeePersistence();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Employee employee) // DOESN'T WORK
    {
        // saving id for the debugging purposes
        long id = persistence.SaveEmployee(employee);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:long}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEmployee(long id) // WORKS
    {
        return Ok(
            new Employee("Bobby", "Smedley",
                         "London", "Teheran",
                         EmployeeGender.M,
                         DepartmentCode.D_21570,
                         "12345678901"));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ListEmployees() // DOESN'T WORK
    {
        return Ok(
            new List<Employee> {
                new Employee("Bobby", "Smedley",
                         "London", "Teheran",
                         EmployeeGender.M,
                         DepartmentCode.D_21570,
                         "12345678901"),

                new Employee("Robbie", "Medleigh",
                         "Liverpool", "Teheran",
                         EmployeeGender.M,
                         DepartmentCode.D_21570,
                         "12345678901")});
    }
}
```

Any idea why get per ID works, but get a list, and post don't work here?

**UPDATE**
Adding `Route` above the `ListEmployees` led to the following issue:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'MyWebService.Models.Employee' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
</ExceptionType>
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us route table?  try to add `[Route]` on ListEmployees

Comment: Try adding `[Route("")]` above the two methods that don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attribute `[Route]` on `ListEmployees` action or check your route table

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: @wesleyy Please show WebApiConfig.cs but not RouteConfig.cs. Error "type failed to serialize the response body for content type" says that you have problem with serialization but not with routing. to test it just replace to `return Ok("Hello")`

Comment: I got it working. I just needed to add an empty constructor to the Employee object to make the serialization succeed. Otherwise, adding [Route] solved the issue. Thanks!